# Why does fetal distress (hypoxia) cause bradycardia?

Tags: physiology, cardiology

In a non stress test performed in the labor room, fetal bradycardia is a danger sign indicating fetal distress (hypoxia).

Why does fetal hypoxia cause bradycardia while hypoxia in adults cause tachycardia? What is the mechanism for both and why is it reverse?

Comment: Are you aware that in adults with hypovolemia, bradycardia is a sign of an impending cardiac arrest? Not saying ths is the answer, but asking if you're aware that the end point is similar.